# clean-docker/Magento2 and PHPStorm

Tags: magento2, docker, phpstorm

Is anyone else here using cleaning docker (or similar) with PHPStorm?  If so, could you please point me in the direction of a few guides to help with getting PHPStorm configured to work?  Clean-docker is setup and working perfectly

[Clean-docker link for reference](https://github.com/clean-docker/Magento2)